# Scroll to anchor after opening fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, anchor, fancybox-2

i have realized a "help"-view in a fancybox. 
In this fancybox i've got a navigation menue. This menue works with anchor links. So far so good.

Now i want to open this fancybox and directly scroll to a spezific anchor.
Here my code, how i open the fancybox:

```
    $.fancybox({
       width       : 1000,
       height      : 800,
       minHeight   : 800,
       maxHeight   : 800,               
       minWidth    : 1000,
       maxWidth    : 1000,
       fitToView   : false,
       autoSize    : true,
       closeClick  : false,
       openEffect  : 'none',
       closeEffect : 'none',
       scrolling   : 'yes',
       href        : "#idofview",
   })
```

I tried a few things, but nothing works.
I tried:

```
location.href = "#anchor";
//or
location.hash = "#anchor";
//or
afterShow: function() {
    $(this).closest('.fancybox-inner').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.fancybox-overlay').scrollTop() + $("#anchorid").offset().top
        });
//or
$(document.body).scrollTop($('#anchorid').offset().top);
```

I also tried to trigger the click of my anchor link:

```
$("#btn_link").trigger('click');
```

Is there any reason to direktly scroll to the anchor in a fancybox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to find the `offset().top` of your targeted anchor first, then just animate the `.fancybox-inner` selector to that position (you don't need this `$(this).closest()` method at all)  so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        afterShow: function () {
            var toScroll = $(".fancybox-inner").find("#anchor2").offset().top - 35;
            $(".fancybox-inner").animate({
                scrollTop: toScroll
            }, 1000);
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that I am subtracting **35px** from the *offset* (in `var toScroll`) because the fancybox's *padding*, but this is a variable you may need to play with.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8jj5mL22/)**